# Why we should not have the collective size of innodb_log_files more than the size of the innodb_buffer_pool

Tags: mysql, crash-recovery

Below is my understanding about the log file group.

Whenever innodb tables were inserted/updated those will be captured in innodb_log_buffer_size.
If the innodb_log_buffer_size filled up or time has come to flush it to the disc, they will be written onto innodb_log_files which are maintained in a group and committed in the table space at the same time.

Now my question is that why we should not have the collective size of innodb_log_files more than the size of the innodb_buffer_pool and why should we write to these log files though we are flushing it to the disc...?

I couldnt able to get proper explanation on this over the web at least I could not  able to understand. Please give me some better explanation.

Really thanks in advance.
Regards,
UDAY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Now my question is that why we should not have the collective size of innodb_log_files more than the size of the innodb_buffer_pool and why should we write to these log files though we are flushing it to the disc...?
```

--> I am not sure where it is mentioned like `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should always be more than this value `innodb_log_files_in_group` * `innodb_log_file_size`. 
Ofcourse! recommended size for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be 70-80% of available memory for Innodb-only installations, should be larger than default which is 8MB.

`innodb_log_buffer_size` a large log buffer enables large transactions to run without a need to write the log to disk before the transactions commit. Thus, if you have big transactions, making the log buffer larger saves disk I/O.

`innodb_log_file_size` The larger the value, the less checkpoint flush activity is needed in the buffer pool, saving disk I/O. But larger log files also mean that recovery is slower in case of a crash. 
You should watch the `Innodb_os_log_written` variable over a period of several minutes, and estimate how many bytes per second are written to your InnoDB transaction logs. You can multiply this value by 3600 (an hour) and divide by `innodb_log_files_in_group` to choose a good log file size.

`innodb_log_buffer_size` uses internally to log to these log files in order to save Disc I/O.

Comment: You can refer to this link for how InnoDB flush method works:
1) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method
2) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-performance-adaptive_flushing.html
read inline 
InnoDB must flush to disk all dirty buffer pool pages whose redo entries are contained in that portion of the log file. When required, InnoDB performs a so-called “sharp checkpoint” by flushing the appropriate dirty pages to make space available in the log file.